# Node.js crashing when client sends invalid packet

Tags: node.js, websocket, buffer

I'm making a multiplayer game with node.js but it crashes when client sends invalid packet.

Server:

```
msg.readFloatLE(1, true);
```

Client:

```
msg.setUint8(1, 1);
```

So, if server is waiting for a float but client sends an int, it crashes with this error:

> C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe: src\node_buffer.cc:752: Assertion
>   `(offset + sizeof(T)) <= (ts_obj_length)' failed.

I'm using [ws library](https://github.com/websockets/ws) but i'm pretty sure that it's about node.js. How can i fix this?

Comment: Why are you reading a float, but setting an int?

Comment: @SterlingArcher I wanted to see if server crashes or not. Everyone can set an int and crash server easily.

Comment: Is it custom wrapper? I don't see these methods in ws.

Comment: @Lazyexpert I'm using node.js' buffer api to read packets. https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html

Comment: Consider using try/catch if your system crashes that easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle exception using `try` `catch`

```
try {
  msg.readFloatLE(1, true);
}
catch(e) {
  console.log(e,"error)
}
```

Comment: But it looks so ugly with try catch. Isn't there any other way to get rid of it?

Comment: Are you kidding. What is ugly here.? It the way we handle exception.

Comment: **Note**: try/catch is only working without second parameter as pointed in @snovakovic's answer.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ved pointed in his answer - try/catch would be the best approach.

Just to suggest something not standard:

```
const defaultCriticalValue = 0.0;
const floatNum = parseFloat('a') || defaultCriticalValue;
msg.readFloatLE(floatNum, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the node documentation for readFloatLE it clearly says it throws exception for your example.

```
// Throws an exception: RangeError: Index out of range
console.log(buf.readFloatLE(1));
```

You can take a look at documentation [here](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_readfloatle_offset_noassert)

The question is what exactly do you try to accomplish? and is readFloatLE right tool for that?